# AVAudioPlayer won't play audio file after AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I create a .caf audio file using AVAudioRecorder and if I try and play it back using AVAudioPlay I get no sound on the iPhone (if played in simulator works fine).  If I close my application and reopen the file plays fine.  Also I am not able to adjust the phone volume after recording unless I close and reopen my application.  Any ideas?

Comment: i am having the same problem. I guess the problem is in recording as the correct settings are not applied.

Answer (score 4):

Was facing the same problem. Solved the problem by setting the AVAudioSession category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback mode. This is my working code:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
audioSession.delegate = self;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:NULL];
[audioSession setActive: YES error: nil];
```

Also make sure that the audio recording has been finished successfully by implementing:

```
   -(void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"Recording success:%@",flag ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
```

And check that you have added `<AVAudioSessionDelegate,AVAudioRecorderDelegate,AVAudioPlayerDelegate>`

in your interface declaration.

Comment: This was exactly my solution. I had made a recording of audio, (mp4) and only could play back if I restarted the app. I am using MPMoviePlayerController to playback, so I think that its a bug on Apples part: When using hardware encode, the AVAudioSessionCategory is NOT reset by making a new player, even if the avaudiorecorder is dealloced, stopped, etc. You need to manually call setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a aac file. I used ima4 before which worked perfectly! I guess the difference is, that aac is hardware and ima4 software decoded. Did you try to reinitialize the player when the file behind got rerecorded? That worked for me!

Markus